# Delete multiple items from grid using CheckboxSelectionModel

Tags: extjs, grid, extjs4, sencha-architect, selectionmodel

Using ExtJs4.1 on Sencha Architect.

I have following code in my onDeleteButton code

```
onDeleteButtonClick: function(button, e, options) {
     var active = this.activeRecord;
     var myGrid = Ext.getCmp('publisherResultsGridView'),
         sm = myGrid.getSelectionModel(),
         selection = sm.getSelection(); // gives you a array of records(models)

     if (selection.length > 0){
            for( var i = 0; i < selection.length; i++) {
                            this.application.log('OnDeleteItemID is ' + selection);
            }
            this.remove(selection);
     }
```

Code for `Remove` Function

```
remove: function(record) {
        var store = Ext.getStore('PublisherProperties');
        store.proxy.url = MasterDataManager.globals.url + "Publishers/";
        store.remove(record);
        store.sync();
```

When I run it, I could see an array of objects in my log, also I dont get any errors after the remove function is executed. But the store doesnt update, I mean it doesnt remove the selected items.

Can somebody please help me.

Thanks

Comment: Can you post how the store is being created.  It sounds like there is a problem with setting up the proxy api. http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.data.proxy.Server-cfg-api.  Or maybe the store in getStore is the wrong one.  Each record has a store property on it, which would be the preferred way to get a reference without using hard-coded ids.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my problem by making the following changes.

To `onDeleteButtonClick`

```
if (selection.length > 0){
                for( var i = 0; i < selection.length; i++) {
                                this.application.log('OnDeleteItemID is ' + selection[i].data.id);
                                this.remove(selection[i]);
                }

         }
```

To `Remove` function

```
remove: function(record) {
    var store = Ext.getStore('PublisherProperties');
    this.application.log('Remove Function is ' + record);
    store.proxy.url = MasterDataManager.globals.url + "Publishers/" + record.data.id;
    store.load({
                        scope : this,
                        callback : function(records, operation, success){
                            if (records.length > 0){
                                var store2 = Ext.getStore('PublisherProperties');
                                        store2.proxy.url = MasterDataManager.globals.url + "Publishers/";
                                        store2.remove(records[0]);
                                        store2.sync();
                             }
                        }
            });
    //store.remove(record);
    //store.sync();
```